# maven compiler plugin error, maybe wrong version?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

after I use my code I get the following error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myProject: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 3.8.1 -> [Help 1]

[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Here's my pom.xml code:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>shitassDiscordBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>3.8.1</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>3.8.1</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>14</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0_227</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I tried changing the maven compiler source and target version to 1.8 but it didn't work. I just want my code to run.
```

Comment: Java version 3.8 does not exist! See: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: So what version should I use for java 14 (jdk 14)?

Comment: As you did for `<maven.compiler.release>`...